# Determine if a point is inside a polygon on a surface

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am developing an algorithm that, given a set of surfaces in 3D and a topology description, describes an object. The edges of the surface are found by tracing the intersection of two surfaces and is stored in a list of points. For a surface to be considered ok, a few conditions has to be met, in particular, the origin of the local coordinate system should be on the surface (c.f. image below). Sometimes, the surface is traced wrongly, and the origin ends up outside the surface. Is there some way to detect this? Had it been in 2D, I would have used winding number, but I cannot find a generalized version of winding number to handle a curve on a surface.

[image]

The functions describing the surfaces are implicit, i.e. I do not have the equation, but I can call a function $f(x,y,z)$ which gives me the signed distance from $x,y,z$ to the surface. Hence, I need to do this computationally.

So, to clarify, the questions should probably be stated as: Given a polygon $P$ on a surface described by the function $f$, can I determine if a point $a$ (also on the surface) is contained within polygon $P$?

The code I am working on is large and well established, hence, changing the way the geometry is described or the way the coordinate systems work is not really possible.

Comment: I think what you are asking is provided a continuous smooth surface of some sorts, to use winding numbers but on curved spaces- to determine if an origin point or any point is on the surface.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is correct. I have updated the post for clarity.

Comment: If you can, create a plane by the target point and find its intersection with the surface. That intersection will consist of a number of curve arcs and your point must belong to one of them. (You can't answer with just the knowledge of the outline, you also need the surface.)

Comment: Alternatively, trace some curve *on the surface* "to infinity" (.i.e. to a point so far that the curve cannot intersect again) and count the number of crossing of the outline.

Comment: Okay I would forget the winding number, and just get the triangle polygon, change to triangular coordinates which are over constrained, then simply change the point to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an ill-defined problem. Couple of pictures to think about

1. Is the point on top of the sphere inside the blue polygon or outside?

[image]

2. Those two surfaces behave similarly in a neighbourhood of a polygon and a point:

[image]

3. A small change in a surface parameter can detach the part of the surface from the polygon. However, to make sure the part of surface with the point isn't connected to the polygon, you would need to effectively brute force every point of the polygon

[image]

However, there are couple of things to consider if your surface are “good enough”:

- Start going along from the point $a$ along the intersection $f=0$ and $x=0$. When you arrive at the polygon boundary, check that you arrived from the right side. (you may select a different plane $y=0$ or take the plane passing through $a$ and two opposite points of the boundary)
- If you know that your surface doesn't have quirks smaller than $d$, then you can use [marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) to build a mesh and then check whether you point belongs to a certain face of the mesh.

Comment: how did you create these images?

Comment: It is indeed an ill-defined problem. However, it is an algorithm that should work for a set of existing objects. Some are very complex, but the tracing algorithm seems to perform very well except in the few cases where the origin ends up outside the polygon.

Comment: Concerning the first image, the edge is positively oriented, so we can actually determine if it is inside the polygon or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seem one ad hoc way to generalize winding number to many surfaces would be simply an orthogonal projection of the surface onto a 2d plane which you can then do winding number in standard sense.

Comment: So like choose suitable direction like maybe average gradient then change coordinate and drop the z coordinate.

Comment: That for generalize winding number.

Comment: Hmm guess that not generalize like closed surface… will delete

Comment: I have considered something similar, but I always find a way such that by projecting on a plane, the point can be located outside the projected curve. Or maybe I do not see it clearly enough?